Differential Operator in Diffusion Equation
The 1D diffusion equation reads:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \phi(x,t)}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( D(\phi, x) \frac{\partial \phi(x,t)}{\partial x} \right)
\end{equation}
where $\phi = \phi(x,t)$ is the concentration of the diffusing substance, $t$ is time, $x$ is the spatial coordinate, and $D(\phi, x)$ is the diffusion coefficient.
My question really boils down to whether or not that is correct or if it should instead be written:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \phi(x,t)}{\partial t} = \frac{d}{d x} \left( D(\phi, x) \frac{\partial \phi(x,t)}{\partial x} \right)
\end{equation}
The difference would be that partial derivative here on $D$ acts on the implicit dependence of $\phi$ with $x$ That is, after the chain rule, if I use a total derivative, I have a term with
$$\frac{d}{d x}  D(\phi, x)$$
Does this become
$$\frac{\partial D}{\partial \phi} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} +\frac{ \partial D}{\partial x}?$$
In my original equation, let's say that I had $D(\phi,x) = \phi^2x.$ Then
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \phi(x,t)}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( D(\phi, x) \frac{\partial \phi(x,t)}{\partial x} \right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \phi^2x \frac{\partial \phi(x,t)}{\partial x} \right)
\end{equation}
And now it looks like the partial derivative will also get applied to the $\phi^2.$

I don't quite understand. What does $d/dx$ mean applied to a function of two variables, $x$ and $t$?

@GReyes See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative

If you had a dependance between $x$ and $t$, it would make sense to take the "total" derivative w.r.t. $t$ (or $x$), but having a function of two independent variables, you have a total differential $dF=\partial F/\partial x dx+\partial F/\partial t dt$ but not something like $dF/dx$.

@GReyes This seems like semantics, I only mentioned the total derivative as a way of getting at the idea I was trying to ask. The point is that the $\partial x$ in the very first equation is ambiguously defined on $D(\phi,x)$ at this point. See the line, "does this become?" We don't have a function of two independent variables because $\phi$ is dependent on $x.$

$\phi$ is a function of $x$ and $t$, which are two independent variables

@GReyes Regardless, is my original question clear to you, or should I try to explain it better? The last sentence in particular of my OP is what I am curious about
